# Translate strings.xml to other languages - Tool for Eclipse?

Tags: android, localization, translation

I'm looking for a good solution to translate my strings.xml to various other languages.
I've heard about motodev but I can't reach this site and it seems to be that this is no longer supported...

Do you know any alternative where I can easily translate my Strings?

Thank you!

Edit: Sorry, i should be more precisely: I want translate the string by myself, i'm just looking for a tool pointing out, which of the strings is not translated yet and which gives the possibility to compare two or more different strings.xml (different languages)

e.g.:

whats your name? | Was ist dein name?
My name is George | ----missing-----

So i dont have to search in each strings.xml if something is missing ...

Greetings and thanks for your replies!

Comment: I had created a tool available here. https://sourceforge.net/projects/androidresourcetranslator/

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way to translate Strings.xml. You will never be able to get a good translation for pretty much any sentence with more than two words unless you have a human do it for you.

I would recommend against automated translations, as after putting some in one of my apps I received numerous mails and bad ratings because of the terrible quality of the translation.

However, if you still want to do it, Google Translate is about as accurate as it gets with machine transactions.